# ¿Que son las conexiones simultáneas a mysql? No he comprendido esto ¿si hago una petición a mysql con php eso cuenta como una conexión?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Por ejemplo si hago lo siguiente:

```html
$resultado = $pide->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $direccion WHERE id = 'visita'");
$filavisita = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
$visitas = "Visitas " . $filavisita['COUNT(*)'] . "\n";
```

¿Esto es establecer una conexión? ¿si 25 personas hicieran esto al mismo tiempo, en algunos servidores bloquearía mi BD? ¿o como cuenta una conexión? En una pagina que realice, cada sección hace una petición a mysql, ¿esto quiere decir que me estoy exponiendo a bloquear mi BD?  En lo que he podido investigar, he visto que hablan de usuarios mysql para no bloquear la BD, ¿esto quiere decir que si creo varios usuarios en la BD puedo tener mas conexiones simultáneas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que estás confundiendo conexión con consultas.

### Conexión a MySQL

Se establece cuando ejecutas instrucciones para que PHP inicialice la librería adecuada para poder ejecutar consultas, por ejemplo:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'mi_usuario', 'mi_contraseña', 'mi_bd');
```

Si 25 personas ingresan a tu sitio al mismo tiempo, seguramente se van a generar 25 conexiones a base de datos.

**Nota:** En casi todos los servidores se asigna determinada cantidad de conexiones por sitio, aplicable a dominio, subdominios, etc. y los usuarios creados en la base de datos no afectan este límite.

### Consulta

Es cualquier instrucción que realice una operación a la base de datos, ya sea para leer, insertar, modificar o eliminar datos (entre muchas otras cosas), por ejemplo:

```
$resultado = $pide->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $direccion WHERE id = 'visita'");
```

En este caso, se entiende que guardaste el recurso de conexión a base de datos en la variable `$pide` y solo estás ejecutando una consulta. De hecho, puedes ejecutar tantas consultas a la base de datos como sea necesario, siempre usando la misma conexión, por ejemplo, ya que contaste con la consulta anterior, podrías paginar:

```
$leer = $pide->query("SELECT * FROM $direccion WHERE id = 'visita' LIMIT 0, 20");
```

### ¿Mi sitio dejará de funcionar?

Ten en cuenta que en una petición HTTP, se ejecuta PHP, conecta a base de datos, realizas todas las consultas necesarias y, al finalizar, se libera la conexión.

Vamos a suponer que solo tienes 25 conexiones disponibles y, en un minuto recibes 100 visitas:

A menos que tu desarrollo sea algo muy pesado, las peticiones no durarán más de un par de segundos y se necesitaría que al menos 26 de esos usuarios accedan exactamente al mismo tiempo para consumir todas las conexiones disponibles y, si es el caso, solo uno de ellos no podrá ver el sitio.

Si llegas a este escenario, te felicito, porque tu sitio se está haciendo popular (no cualquiera tiene 100 visitas en un minuto) y necesitarás incrementar la cantidad de conexiones, probablemente migrando a un servidor con más capacidad.

### Errores de programación que se deben evitar

De hecho es solo un error y la forma de evitarlo es bastante simple: **Usa solo una conexión para realizar todas las consultas en cada petición**

He visto programas que hacen esto cada que necesitan acceder a la base de datos:

- Conectan a base de datos
- Realizan **una** consulta
- Cierran conexión
- Para el siguiente acceso a base de datos, repiten la operación

Dependiendo de la complejidad del desarrollo, esta mala práctica puede hacer que en una misma petición se usen todas las conexiones disponibles.

Comment: De hecho, si un sitio recibe 100 visitas en 1 minuto y tarda digamos 3 segundos en cargar... cada conexión podrá cargar 20 páginas en 1 minuto, con lo cual para atender 100 visitas en 1 minuto, si la media de tiempo de procesamiento de cada una es 3 segundos, tan solo hacen falta 5 conexiones (5 * 20 = 100) con lo cual es bastante complicado para la mayoría de páginas superar un límite de conexiones de 25 (Serían 500 visitas por minuto suponiendo 3s de tiempo de procesamiento!)

Comment: Eh, valdría la pena aclarar que una conexión abre un socket al puerto de la BD y crea una sesión en el motor. Una consulta usa una conexión ya establecida. El ejemplo básico abre la conexión, la usa y la cierra. Un pool de conexiones mantiene una única conexión y un número de sesiones iniciadas para reusarlas. Y bueh, 2s en una consulta es un montón de tiempo.

Comment: @Benito-B, es un caso hipotético un poco extremo, realmente es difícil determinar en qué momento la cantidad de usuarios concurrentes va a generar error por falta de conexiones disponibles.

Comment: @Alfabravo, traté de mantenerme alejado de tecnicismos para no confundir al usuario. Respecto al pool de conexiones, lo voy a investigar ahora, pero sí recuerdo un caso como el expuesto. Por último, estoy de acuerdo en que 2s por petición es mucho tiempo, pero solo es un ejemplo, tampoco creo que haya una forma fácil de determinar cuánto debe tardar una petición, porque dependerá de los procesos que se realicen y si son realmente necesarios o no. Tema muy subjetivo.

Comment: ¡Woow mil gracias por tan valiosa información! Lo pregunto porque un cliente me ha pedido un juego “sencillo” en línea, en donde cree que al menos estarán 500 personas en un evento streaming que realizará, y en que les hará preguntas que deben contestar lo antes posible. Esto quiere decir, si entendí bien, que en este caso desde que se inicia el juego, se establecerán  varias conexiones y después varias consultas, y en este caso en particular, si se pueden dar más de 100 conexiones en un minuto, ya que deben responder y conectarse cuando el conductor del programa se los indique.

Comment: Y también se corre el riesgo de que 25 personas entren a la página al mismo tiempo, ya que el conductor les indicará a las “500 personas” en un momento determinado del streaming, y la mayoría estará atenta para entrar, concursar y ganar un premio.

Comment: @Triby Por supuesto que es un caso hipotético, y extremo. Si una página tarda 3s en cargar habría que mirar qué está pasando! Además nunca entrarán en intervalos exactos. Era solo para ejemplificar lo "difícil" que es alcanzar el límite de conexiones en una web general.

Comment: @Abner El número real de conexiones simultaneas de mysql es bastante mayor a 25 normalmente. Según la documentación de [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections) el valor por defecto es ilimitadas, y el máximo 4294967295, así que dudo que vayas a tener problemas con mysql. No estoy seguro de si php en sí mismo tiene un límite también

Comment: @Benito-B, Creo que esto lo determina la empresa de hosting. En sus planes de web hosting dice 25 conexiones simultáneas a Mysql y 25 procesos simultáneos, hay algunos que tienen hasta 50 (creo lo hacen por protección). Estuve revisando y para algo como un juego, chat, etc, recomiendan dedicados o vps, en donde dependerá de la capacidad y no del limite que te asignen.

Comment: @Abner, hace algunos años, en un servidor VPS con alrededor de 100 conexiones disponibles, realizaba encuestas de evaluación docente para una escuela estatal. No recuerdo las métricas exactas, pero creo que llegamos a tener al menos 1,000 usuarios "al mismo tiempo" y nunca tuvimos inconvenientes. Por supuesto, habría que revisar la lógica para mostrar y procesar las preguntas del juego.

Comment: @Abner, en ese caso, si los 500 usuarios van a intentar responder en cuanto el presentador indique, sí podría ser que más de 25 intenten conectarse en el "mismo segundo", por lo que debes optimizar tu código para que el proceso sea lo más rápido posible y tratar de evitar que se consuman todas las conexiones. Es posible lograrlo, pero necesitas realizar pruebas antes de iniciar el evento y, dependiendo de los resultados, considerar cambiar a otro servicio con mejores características.